# Javascript array value not printing

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to do ElementName get value from ElementId?

```
var Elements = {
    ElementId: '#myelement',
    ElementName: Elements.ElementId
};

alert(Elements.ElementName);
```

Comment: The object doesn't exist while it's being defined. So assign that property after you've created the first, or use a constructor function if this is suitable to represent some commonly defined object.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't created the object yet, so it's not going to be defined. You can define that property on the object once it's created like this:

```js
var Elements = {
  ElementId: '#myelement'
};

Elements['ElementName'] = Elements.ElementId;

alert(Elements.ElementName);
```

However I think there's a better way; what specifically are you using the `name` and `id` properties for?